# WooCommerce hooks and overriding templates

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have started to learn how to create templates with WooCommerce and I had faced with a little problem. For instance, in the php file content-single-product.php of Woocommerce plugin I have strings like that:

```
     <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );

    ?>
```

And for example, when I want to edit this (delete some fields and change the structure) I try erase the string:

> do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );

and after that write like this:

```
<?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
         * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
         */
        //do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
        do_action('woocommerce_template_single_title');
    ?>
```

Could you tell me please why this doesn't work?

What is the right way to edit like that?

Thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Yeah! Thank you so much! You're really helpful person! Take care!

Comment: Thanks … I try too. Hooks and templates are not easy when beginning on WooCommerce/WP. See you around… Thanks again.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

**Starting note:** Always try to use first available hooks, then if you have no other choice, you can override available templates via your child theme.

First in **reference below** you will find how to [**override properly woocommerce templates** via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) *(avoiding editing the plugin templates)*.

In your first code snippet, as you can see for **`woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook**, you have in order all the different templates that are **`@hooked`** in this **hook location** with **`do_action()`** WordPress function:

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
```

So in your customized code (the 2nd code snippet) you have just replaced the **hook**, by the **hooked template slug** *(that is **NOT** a hook)* and will **NOT** work as an entry point **action hook**. See the references at the bottom of this answer for the [list of WooCommerce actions and filters **existing hooks**](https://woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/)…

> **Consequences:** All other hooked templates in the commented list code (beginning with *@hooked*) will be missing **if you replace a hook by a template slug**.

**For the hooks used in the templates** see this helpful [WooCommerce Visual Hook Guide](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html)

---

#### Explanations *(How to)*:

**HOW TO - Concrete example:**

You want **to customize `woocommerce_template_single_title` hooked template** in **`woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook**.

```
 THE HOOK NAME:  woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
   
 THE TEMPLATES HOOKED (+priority order number)  => corresponding template file name:    
— woocommerce_template_single_title       (5) => single-product/title.php
— woocommerce_template_single_rating     (10) => single-product/rating.php
— woocommerce_template_single_price      (10) => single-product/price.php
— woocommerce_template_single_excerpt    (20) => single-product/short-description.php
— woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart(30) => single-product/add-to-cart/ (6 files depending on product type)
— woocommerce_template_single_meta       (40) => single-product/review-meta.php
— woocommerce_template_single_sharing -  (50) => single-product/share.php
```

Then you will need to **edit** the corresponding **`woocommerce_single_product_summary` hook** **`title.php`** located in **`single-product`** *(sub folder)*… Finally is not so complicated, once we understand the template structure files and the hooks in that templates.

The **priority number**, gives the order for the hooked templates: Smaller in first, bigger at the end…

See also: [Hooks and their hooked functions execution queue in Wordpress and Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52765303/are-hooked-functions-added-to-a-queue-or-do-they-override-each-other-in-wordpres)

---

#### Others ways:

> **You can also use all that existing templates hooks** to target very specific changes or customizations, with custom functions located in the **`function.php`** file of your active child theme (or theme) or any plugin file too.

**Example using `add_action()` WordPress function:**

```
// define the woocommerce_single_product_summary callback function

function my_custom_action() { 
    echo '<p>This is my custom action function</p>';
};     
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'my_custom_action', 15 );
```

This function has a priority number of **`15`**  and will display
*"This is my custom action function"* string text, between the **`product price`** and the **`product short description`**…

**Optional arguments** of this hooked function for this hook:
• The template slug *(string)*.
• The priority *(int)*.

---

References:

- [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- [WooCommerce Hooks: Actions and filters](https://woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/)
- [WooCommerce Code - Action and Filter Hook Reference](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html)
- [WooCommerce Visual Hook Guides (for all WooCommerce pages)](https://www.businessbloomer.com/category/woocommerce-tips/visual-hook-series/)

Comment: Thank you sir. this is really helpfull!

Comment: I have one doubt in this, How to change the priority order number?

Comment: I tried like this 
function action_woocommerce_single_product_review() {

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_review', 1, 0 );   but it's showing below the title

Comment: @user9437856 Ask a new question including your code and explanations please.

Comment: This link in the post needs to be updated `list of WooCommerce actions and filters existing hooks…`