# Adjust the text below returning customer

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, checkout

I want to change the text at the checkout page below the returning customer bar, namely *"If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details below. If you are a new customer, please proceed to the Billing & Shipping section."*.

The text seems to be present in: `plugins\woocommerce\i18n\languages\woocommerce.pot`
and `plugins\woocommerce\templates\checkout\form-login.php`

I know I can simply adjust the text in those files; but if WooCommerce gets updated it will be overwritten.

Is there a way to change this text with hooks, although the text doesn't appear in my theme?

I don't want to use a plugin for this if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [Overriding Woocommerce templates via a child theme *(or a theme)*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/#section-1) you will not loose any changes when Woocommerce plugin is updated.

So in your case, as explained on the comment of the template `checkout\form-login.php` you will have to copy this file to your child theme:

```
/**
 * Checkout login form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-login.php.
```

> **Woocommerce templates are made to be overridden via a child theme (or theme)**

See: [WooCommerce action hooks and overriding templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063958/woocommerce-action-hooks-and-overriding-templates/39064240#39064240)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a template override you can use the gettext filter added to child theme functions.php:

```
/////////////////////////////
//Change Wooocommerce Text
add_filter( 'gettext', 'mywc_strings', 20, 3 );

  function mywc_strings( $translated_text, $text, $domain ) {

    switch ( $translated_text ) {

        case 'If you have shopped with us before, please enter your details below. If you are a new customer, please proceed to the Billing section.' :
            $translated_text = __( 'If you have an account please login, otherwise continue to billing. ', 'woocommerce' );
            break; 
            
          } 

        //change login text also:
        case 'Click here to login' :
            $translated_text = __( 'Login', 'woocommerce' );
            break;              
  
        
    return $translated_text;
}
```

Also you can change the "Returning customer?" text:

```
//Change "Returning customer?" text

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_login_message', 'mywc_return_customer_message' );
 
  function mywc_return_customer_message() {

  return 'Customer account: ';

}
```

Answer (score -1):

While working on a custom theme, you can achieve this functionality by copying same template to your-theme/woocommerce/checkout/form-login.php.

Now you can update plugin without losing the changes.

Comment: Welcome. SO is designed so that useful answers should be upvoted, NOT duplicated. In this case, the post has less info than the accepted answer, and adds nothing. Additionally, it reads more like a Comment than a complete, self contained Answer, as defined by SO guidelines. Edit, if you can add new, useful information or consider deleting. Left as is, the platform may delete this post, as "not an Answer". Notice how the accepted answer has follow up links to documentation, and example code