# Move product meta to the description tab in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

How to move the product meta to the beginning of the product description tab?
I try:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs_description', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 10 );
```

Remove works, but `add_action()` doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep the first code line. Then to insert single product meta on product description tab, before description, you can use 2 different ways:

**1). Using Hooks as follows:**

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );

add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woocommerce_custom_product_tabs', 999 );
function woocommerce_custom_product_tabs( $tabs ) {
    // We overwrite the callback function with a custom one
    $tabs['description']['callback'] = 'woocommerce_product_meta_and_description_tab';

    // (optional) We can also overwrite the title
    $tabs['description']['title'] = __('Meta and description', 'woocommerce');

    return $tabs;
}

function woocommerce_product_meta_and_description_tab() { // this is where you indicate what appears in the description tab
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/meta.php' ); // The meta content first
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/tabs/description.php' ); // The product description after
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**2). Or Overriding templates:**

You can override `single-product/tabs/description.php` template file via your theme as explained in [this official documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

Once you have copied the file to the `woocommerce` folder inside your active theme, open edit `single-product/tabs/description.php` file and add the following line inside it:

```
wc_get_template( 'single-product/meta.php' );
```

It will displays the product meta information inside the product description tab.

Don't forget to keep in your active child theme's functions.php file:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_meta', 40 );
```

Related: [WooCommerce action hooks and overriding templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063958/woocommerce-action-hooks-and-overriding-templates/39064240#39064240)

Answer (score -1):

There actually is a way to do this within your functions without copying files from `woocommerce` and overriding them in your child theme.

Per WooCommerce documentation, you can customize the product data tabs. With a small modification to the code they provided, you can do what you're asking:

```
/**
 * Customize product data tabs
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_custom_description_tab', 98 );
function woo_custom_description_tab( $tabs ) {

    $tabs['description']['callback'] = 'woo_custom_description_tab_content';    // Custom description callback

    return $tabs;
}

function woo_custom_description_tab_content() { // this is where you indicate what appears in the description tab
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/meta.php' ); // add this to add meta to content
    the_content(); // keep this in to preserve original functionality
}
```