# How to edit the output of "woocommerce_thankyou" hook in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am sure this have beed asked many time. I even got on few answers but I realy dont get the idea of how to edit any "action" or "filter" hooks in Wordpress + WooCommerce.

As an example on checkout page, at the bottom where is usually the summary of the shopping cart, this info is generated by this code:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>
```

I tried different way to search for "woocommerce_thankyou" in other files but I cant find anything. So, how the output code is generated? There must be a file which is called for doing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You simply missed the WooCommerce plugin file [`includes/wc-template-hooks.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-hooks.php) where the action hook `woocommerce_thankyou` [is called on line 260](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L260) triggering `woocommerce_order_details_table()` function, which is located on [`includes/wc-template-functions.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php) from [line 2641 to 2560](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2541-L2560):

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'woocommerce_order_details_table' ) ) {

    /**
     * Displays order details in a table.
     *
     * @param mixed $order_id Order ID.
     */
    function woocommerce_order_details_table( $order_id ) {
        if ( ! $order_id ) {
            return;
        }

        wc_get_template(
            'order/order-details.php',
            array(
                'order_id' => $order_id,
            )
        );
    }
}
```

As you can see this function calls the WooCommerce template [`order/order-details.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details.php), that outputs the related order details.

So you will have to edit the WooCommerce template [`order/order-details.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/order/order-details.php) to make changes. **But this template is used many times on other pages.**

So you can target the WooCommerce thankyou page using  `is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received')` conditional tag and you will be able to override this template using it like:

```
if ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) {
    // The altered code for the thankyou page
} else {
    // The normal code for all other pages
}
```

---

Related: [WooCommerce action hooks and overriding templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063958/woocommerce-action-hooks-and-overriding-templates/39064240#39064240)