# How to Identify the code used by WooCommerce hook 'woocommerce_view_order'

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Within WooCommerce I have been making some edits to templates. So far this has been straight forward.

Now I am trying to add some columns into the 'Order Details' table under 'my-account > view-order'.

I am in the template view-order.php which is a template under 'myaccount' in WooCommerce.

Instead of seeing some code in a template to edit, I am seeing the following code:

```
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', $order_id ); ?>
```

Where is the code from this action called and can I edit it?

Thanks for all time and help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WooCommerce action hooks and overriding templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063958/woocommerce-action-hooks-and-overriding-templates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at WooCommerce plugin [`includes/wc-template-hooks.php` core file (line 259)](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/wc-template-hooks.php#L259):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'woocommerce_order_details_table', 10 );
```

As you can see, the function `woocommerce_order_details_table()` is hooked in. So now let's find this function that is located in [`includes/wc-template-functions.php` core file (starting line 2584)](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2584-L2603).

As you will see [this hooked function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.2/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L2584-L2603) call the [template file `order/order-details.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.1/templates/order/order-details.php).

So now you can make some changes:

1). Overriding the [template file `order/order-details.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.5.1/templates/order/order-details.php) via your active child theme or theme as explained [in this documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/).

**Note:** The template file `order/order-details.php` is also used in Order received (thankyou), so take care to target your changes using the following condition:

```php
// For view order
if ( is_wc_endpoint_url( 'view-order' ) ) {
    // Here your changes
} 
// For other cases
else {
    // Here keep the original code
}
```

---

2). Or/and you could also remove this hooked function to replace it by your own custom function, with something like:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'woocommerce_order_details_table', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_view_order', 'custom_order_details_table', 10 );
function custom_order_details_table( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! $order_id ) {
        return;
    }

    // Here below add your own custom code
}
```

> You can also call your own custom template in that custom function, that will be used exclusively in order view endpoint...

**Related:** [WooCommerce action hooks and overriding templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063958/woocommerce-action-hooks-and-overriding-templates/39064240#39064240)

**WooCommerce Documentations:**

- [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)
- [WooCommerce Conditional Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/#section-11)