# Move single product stars rating in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, review

I am learning WooCommerce development. I would like to display the stars rating at top of the heading so I tried like this (Not a review, it's just an example):

```
 function action_woocommerce_single_product_review() {
      //I don't want to show any content here    
 } 
  add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_review', 1, 0 );
```

I also tried using jQuery which is working:

```
$(".woocommerce-product-rating").insertBefore('.product_title');
```

Comment: See the hooks visual guide and priority here - you can move the block by changing the priority  https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

Comment: @mujuonly, I just added  add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'action_woocommerce_single_product_review', 1, 0 );
 but nothing is working

Comment: I have a review on my page and i have to show that on top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move stars ratings before product title in single product pages use:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_rating', 3 );
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [WooCommerce action hooks and overriding templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063958/woocommerce-action-hooks-and-overriding-templates/39064240#39064240)

Comment: Give me sometime to check

Comment: I think some little bit confusion here from my side. I am talking about the this review https://prnt.sc/xd0pq5

Comment: I apologize, Yes not it's working. Thank you so much.

Comment: Incase if i  use any plugin (Pincode checker) and I have to show any paragraph then below that then what number i have to use it?

Comment: Sure. Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.

Comment: I think you deleted your last comment. Can you undo your comment?

Comment: @user9437856 Between hook priority 3 used here and product title using priority 5, you can logically use a hooked function with priority 4 to insert something in between.

Comment: I used pinchecker plugin and that displaying above the add to cart button. screenshot here https://prnt.sc/xftmpn

Comment: @user9437856 I don't know anything about this plugin, sorry.

Comment: Let me ask a new question. Please help me if you know the answer.

Comment: @user9437856 Yes you can do that… Maybe someone can help too.

Comment: Can you help me out with this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897369/how-to-separate-the-login-and-register-page-and-access-using-shortcode