# How to show the login and register form on two different pages with WooCommerce using templates

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have a my-account page which is displaying the `login` and `register` form. Below is the screenshot. There is no CSS as of now.

[image]

My issue is, I have to separate both the pages. I mean I have to create a login and register both pages separately.

This is the whole code `form-login.php`

```
<?PHP
/**
 * Login Form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files, and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce\Templates
 * @version 4.1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' ); ?>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

<div class="u-columns col2-set" id="customer_login">

    <div class="u-column1 col-1">

<?php endif; ?>

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

            <p class="form-row">
                <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox woocommerce-form-login__rememberme">
                    <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                </label>
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

    </div>

    <div class="u-column2 col-2">

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
                </p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>

            <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

                <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                    <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
                </p>

            <?php else : ?>

                <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row form-row">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

    </div>

</div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' ); ?>
```

I found two links on Stack Overflow:

[How to create separate log-in and registration pages in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41962909/how-to-create-separate-log-in-and-registration-pages-in-woocommerce)

[Separate registration page in WooCommerce website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821488/separate-registration-page-in-woocommerce-website)

I found this code

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['action']) == 'register' ) {
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-register.php' );
} else {
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-login-single.php' );
}
?>
```

I have several questions:

1. Where should I add this code?
2. Do I need to create a login and register page in WordPress?
3. Or do I need to create a login and register inside my-account like `form-login-1.php` and `form-register-1` and add a code separately with a shortcode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create two separate pages for the login form and the registration form it is necessary to have 3 templates. Using templates, *you won't have to change a single line of functions.php*.

This snippet:

```
<?php
if( isset($_GET['action']) == 'register' ) {
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-register.php' );
} else {
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-login-single.php' );
}
?>
```

has the purpose of loading the template of the login form or the template of the registration form **based on the url of the page**.

The goal will be:

- if the page url is `www.yourdomain.com/my-account/`, the login form is loaded
- if the page url is `www.yourdomain.com/my-account/?action=register`, the registration form is loaded

#### PREMISE

To view the registration form correctly, you must enable the *"Allow customers to create an account on the My account page"* function.

From the Wordpress admin page go to: **WooCommerce** > **Settings** > **Accounts & Privacy**.

[image]

#### CHILD THEME

> All templates must be loaded within your **child theme** (otherwise they
> will be overwritten at the next WooCommerce plugin update).
>
> The directory is: `/your-child-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/`

#### TEMPLATES

It is necessary to have 3 template files:

1. **`form-login.php`**: the template that is loaded when the user is not logged in.
2. **`form-login-single-page.php`**: the template that will contain the login form
3. **`form-register-single-page.php`**: the template that will contain the registration form

**form-login.php** `/your-child-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Login Form (by default)
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

if( isset( $_GET['action'] ) == 'register' ) {
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-register-single-page.php' );
} else {
    wc_get_template( 'myaccount/form-login-single-page.php' );
}
```

**form-login-single-page.php** `/your-child-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-login-single-page.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Login Form
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_customer_login_form' ); ?>

<div class="u-columns col2-set" id="customer_login">

    <div class="u-column1 col-1">

        <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Login', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

        <form class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-login login" method="post">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_start' ); ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username or email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form' ); ?>

            <p class="form-row">
                <label class="woocommerce-form__label woocommerce-form__label-for-checkbox woocommerce-form-login__rememberme">
                    <input class="woocommerce-form__input woocommerce-form__input-checkbox" name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> <span><?php esc_html_e( 'Remember me', 'woocommerce' ); ?></span>
                </label>
                <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-login', 'woocommerce-login-nonce' ); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" name="login" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
                <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>?action=register" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register" name="register"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            </p>
            <p class="woocommerce-LostPassword lost_password">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Lost your password?', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
            </p>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_login_form_end' ); ?>

        </form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_customer_login_form' ); ?>
```

**form-register-single-page.php** `/your-child-theme/woocommerce/myaccount/form-register-single-page.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * Register Form
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly.
}

?>

<?php if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_enable_myaccount_registration' ) ) : ?>

<div class="u-column2 col-2">

    <h2><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h2>

    <form method="post" class="woocommerce-form woocommerce-form-register register" <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_tag' ); ?> >

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start' ); ?>

        <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_username' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_username"><?php esc_html_e( 'Username', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="text" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="username" id="reg_username" autocomplete="username" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['username'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['username'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
            </p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="reg_email"><?php esc_html_e( 'Email address', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="email" id="reg_email" autocomplete="email" value="<?php echo ( ! empty( $_POST['email'] ) ) ? esc_attr( wp_unslash( $_POST['email'] ) ) : ''; ?>" /><?php // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine ?>
        </p>

        <?php if ( 'no' === get_option( 'woocommerce_registration_generate_password' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-form-row woocommerce-form-row--wide form-row form-row-wide">
                <label for="reg_password"><?php esc_html_e( 'Password', 'woocommerce' ); ?>&nbsp;<span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input type="password" class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" name="password" id="reg_password" autocomplete="new-password" />
            </p>

        <?php else : ?>

            <p><?php esc_html_e( 'A password will be sent to your email address.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form' ); ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-form-row form-row">
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-register', 'woocommerce-register-nonce' ); ?>
            <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-Button woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-register__submit" name="register" value="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Register', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') ); ?>" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login" name="login"><?php esc_attr_e( 'Log in', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        </p>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_end' ); ?>

    </form>

</div>

<?php endif;
```

#### RESULT

**Login form**
`www.yourdomain.com/my-account/`

[image]

**Register form**
`www.yourdomain.com/my-account/?action=register`

[image]

#### NOTE

The **Username** and **Password** fields will be visible or hidden according to the respective options selected on the administration page: **WooCommerce** > **Settings** > **Accounts & Privacy**:

- *When creating an account, automatically generate an account username for the customer based on their name, surname or email*
- *When creating an account, automatically generate an account password*

The templates have been tested and work.

#### CUSTOM FIELDS

Feel free to modify the templates to your liking. **You can edit** or **add custom fields**. In the latter case, remember to validate and save the data of the custom fields. You can use the following hooks:

- `woocommerce_register_form`: to add custom fields
- `woocommerce_process_registration_errors`: to validate the fields
- `user_register`: save custom fields as user meta

Comment: Give me some time to check your answer.

Comment: I added all the code according to the answer. Now how can I access the login and register URL?

Comment: On the page `www.yourdomain.com/my-account` you will find the login form (if you are not logged in) and next to the "Log in" button you will also find "Register". Of course you can customize it by modifying the template and/or adding CSS styles.

Comment: I also added screenshots of the result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Give me some time to implement your answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, Yes, It's working. Upvote from my side.

Comment: Do have any idea about this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65937075/how-to-create-a-password-and-confirm-password-on-register-page-on-woocommerce