# how to customize the registration section of my woocommerce account

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am new creating a plugin for woocommerse,

I am creating a plugin that does a pre-registration, where I add custom fields that allow me to store the information in a temporary table, which generates a verification email so the user can have a registration real, I avoid the accumulation of incomplete records in the WP database,

my problem is that I can't delete the fields that woocommerse generates by default and my custom field seems to be overwritten

[image]

verifique diferentes formas, esta es una de ellas en la que intento eliminar el campo pero sigue igual

```
//deshabilitar_campos_por_defecto----
function deshabilitar_campos_por_defecto() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'woocommerce_register_form' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'deshabilitar_campos_por_defecto', 1 );

// Función para agregar campos personalizados al formulario de registro de WooCommerce------------------------------------------------------

function agregar_campos_personalizados_registro() {

    ?>
    <p class="form-row">
        <label for="nombre">Nombre Usuario<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="nombre" id="nombre" required="required" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row">
        <label for="apellido">Apellido Usuario<span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="apellido" id="apellido" required="required" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row">
        <label for="email">Correo Electrónico <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="email" class="input-text" name="email" id="email" required="required" />
    </p>
    <p class="form-row">
        <input type="submit" class="button wp-element-button" name="register" value="Registrar" />
    </p>
    <?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_register_form', 'agregar_campos_personalizados_registro');
```

Comment: Instead, you need to override via your child theme [the template file `myaccount/form-login.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.1/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/form-login.php).  See [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) and [WooCommerce hooks and overriding templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063958/woocommerce-hooks-and-overriding-templates/39064240#39064240)